# statsmodels' mosaic plot with empty values

Tags: python, statsmodels, mosaic-plot

I would like to create a mosaic plot with [`statsmodels.graphics.mosaicplot.mosaic()`](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/stable/generated/statsmodels.graphics.mosaicplot.mosaic.html) with data that casts empty cells.  They look ugly in the resulting plot, because a cell is created irrespective of its size.

Example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.graphics.mosaicplot import mosaic

df = pd.DataFrame({'size' : ['small', 'large', 'large'],
                   'length' : ['long', 'short', 'long']})

print(df)  # note that the 'short'-'small' combination is missing

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
mosaic(df, ax=ax)
```

creates a plot with an empty cell for value "short small":

[image]

Is there a way to either avoid the creation of this cell or to remove it from the plot afterwards?

Comment: What exactly do you want? I don't see any empty cell which is to be expected. So what exactly is wrong here? The image is also super tiny and hard to read given that size.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Now i see what you mean. Is Nickil's answer what you wanted? (keep in mind, that the code is python3-tailored in regards to dict-iteration)

Comment: @sascha: For convenience I enlarged the image (from middle to large). Between the red block for a and the green block for c you'll find the thick white stripe, with c in the center. That's the empty cell. The thick white stripe is due to the margin around cells.

Comment: @sascha No it doesn't, but that's my fault.  I updated my question because I am actually using a DataFrame to create a two-dimensional mosaic plot.

Answer (score 2):

Send an anonymous function to exclude labels whose values are 0:

```
labels = lambda k: "\n".join(k) if df[k] != 0 else ""
mosaic(df, ax=ax, labelizer=labels)
```

Comment: I get a long traceback with `KeyError: ('small', 'long')` at the end. I tried `df.get(k, 0)` instead with an even longer traceback giving a `ValueError: Can only output finite numbers in PDF`.

Comment: I just used lambda _: ""